# Average distance moved by a permutation

Tags: permutations

For each $\pi$ permutation of numbers 1 to n, $f(\pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n |\pi_i - i|$. What is the average of $f(\pi)$ on all of the $n=7$ permutations?

Comment: Often, looking at smaller examples can help you uncover patterns that help you solve larger examples. Have you tried calculating the average for, say, $n = 2, 3$ or $4$?

Comment: @Arthur You right but in fact i couldn't even understand the question well

Comment: @Developer The question is asking: What is $\frac{1}{7!}\sum_\pi f(\pi)$, where $\pi$ in the sum runs through all permutations of $\left\{1,\ldots,7\right\}$?

Comment: Say $\pi$ is the cyclic permutation that sends $k\mapsto k+1$, except $7\mapsto 1$. Then $$f(\pi)=1+1+1+1+1+1+6=12$$ You are asked to calculate this value for _all_ different $\pi$, sum them up, and divide by $7!$.

Comment: Please add context to your question.  A short question body will trigger [an alarm](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49890861#49890861).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thanks for your suggestion, can you please tell me what kind of details can I add to my question body when there are no details?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: not sure which guideline is not met

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this for a general $n$, instead of $7$.

We have $$E(f(\pi)) = E \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |\pi_i - i| \right).$$ By linearity of expectation, we get

$$ E(f(\pi)) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(|\pi_i - i|). $$

Now $E(|\pi_i - i|)$ of course depends on $i$ and $n$. In particular, we have

$$ E(|\pi_i - i|) = {(i-1) + (i-2) + \cdots + 1 + 0 + 1 + \cdots + (n-i) \over n}. $$

Then we have $(i-1) + (i-2) + \cdots + 1 = i(i-1)/2$ and $1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-i) = (n-i)(n-i+1)/2$.  This gives

$$ E(|\pi_i - i|) = {i(i-1)/2 + (n-i)(n-i+1)/2 \over n} $$

Therefore, going back to the initial sum, $$E(f(\pi)) = \sum_{i=1}^n {i(i-1) \over 2n} + \sum_{i=1}^n {(n-i)(n-i+1) \over 2n}.$$

These tw sums are the same since they have the same terms in reverse order, so we get

$$ E(f(\pi)) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n {i(i-1) \over 2n} = {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n i^2-i$$

Finally we can work out that sum:

$$ {1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n (i^2-i) = {1 \over n} (\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 - \sum_{i-1}^n i) = {1 \over n} \left( {n(n+1)(2n+1) \over 6} - {n(n+1) \over 2} \right) = (n+1) \left( {2n+1 \over 6} - {1 \over 2} \right) = {(n+1)(2n-2) \over 6} = {n^2 - 1 \over 3}.$$

The references at https://oeis.org/A062869 appear to be relevant; the statistic computed here is called the "total displacement" of a permutation or "Spearman's disarray".

Comment: see also https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112210